# Custom View Adapter for GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a GridView layout and want to populate it with generic Views (Button, TextView, EditText, and custom views). I have tried the basic ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<View> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<View>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currentList);
```

Where currentList is an ArrayList

Unfortunately it gives me an error and from what I've read online I need a custom adapter, but all of the custom adapters need you to inflate an xml file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you need to use custom adapter. yes you need to inflate a custom xml for each row in listview

Comment: But what do I inflate? All of this is being done dynamically.

Comment: inflate a custom layout. create a class `public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter` override `getView` inflate custom layout with editext and buttons. set the custom adapter to gridview. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ instead of listview use gridview. the concept is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayadapter shouldn't be a collection of views because the views get recycled.  Instead it should be a collection of objects that contains the data needed for that particular item.

the adapters getView will return the containing view.  Normally you would just inflate a layout but there's nothing stopping you from dynamically creating a ViewGroup like a linear layout and then adding each view in code.

Layouts are very flexible however and in most cases you don't actually need to do it dynamically.  If you study up on view types you will see that it's easy to manage disticnt layouts based on the item type you want to display